# Error in SQL syntax at line 1 php/sql

Tags: php, mysql

The first problem was with mysql_query which returns FALSE and mysql_num_rows expects parameter 1 to be resource not a boolean. I ve made this to get the error

```
if($itemsres === FALSE)
   die(mysql_error());
```

Now i have this error " You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require("header.php");
require("functions.php");
echo "<h1>Your shopping cart</h1>";
showcart();
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM']) == TRUE) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM orderitems WHERE order_id = " . 
  $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] . ";";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numrows >= 1) {
  echo "<h2><a href='checkout-address.php'>Go to the checkout</a></h2>";
 }
} 
 require("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Use prepared statements please.

Comment: What is the value of `$_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM']`? Also note that the `mysql_*` API has been deprecated since PHP 5.5, and **removed entirely** in PHP7. You should use `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statements when writing new code.

Comment: Don't terminate the statement with a semicolon. Mysql doesn't like multiple statements like that but, as Qirel points out, PDO is taking over so I'd recommend using that.

Comment: @Mike The semicolon is valid like that, but anything after the semicolon wouldn't be ;-) And I always encourage anyone moving from `mysql_*` to try out both PDO and `mysqli_*` - they're somewhat different, but they both do a solid job, and by trying both, you'd find which one you prefer (although any experienced developer knows both!).

Comment: True, Qirel, although I already had a database-agnostic class so I leaped on PDO like a shot! Thanks for the heads-up - it's been 10 years since I tried multiple statements so I only had a vague recollection about semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error

Use query like this

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM orderitems WHERE order_id = $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM']";
```

Or

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orderitems WHERE order_id = ".$_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'];
```

Or

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM orderitems WHERE order_id = '$_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM']'";
```

NOTE: SQL Injection.

PS: Use prepared statements

```
$loginrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($loginres);
session_start();
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'] = 1;
$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $loginrow['username'];
$_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] = $loginrow['id'];
$ordersql = "SELECT id FROM orders WHERE customer_id = " . 
$_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] . " AND status < 2"; 
$orderres = 
mysql_query($ordersql); $orderrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($orderres); 
$_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] = 
$orderrow['id'];    }
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\site1\cart\showcart.php on line 9 /// this is the error i get for the first and third example and for the second one it s the same  as mine.

Comment: There are three type of syntax, did you try all? Which one gives error?

Comment: I want you to check the value in $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM']

Comment: i tried all of them. the second one shows the same sql error as mine and the other ones the error " 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\site1\cart\showcart.php on line 9

Comment: I don't think you have value in your session

Comment: and i put that echo $sql to  check the value in $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] but nothing appears

Comment: Do this var_dump($_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] and check if it has value or not

Comment: put var_dump line after `session_start()`

Comment: Exactly, you have nothing in your session variable. That is why query isn't working.

Comment: and what should i do ?

Comment: Now  copy paste my code to your code and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem started from here.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']))
{
 $custsql = "SELECT id, status from orders WHERE customer_id = ". 
 $_SESSION['SESS_USERID']. " AND status < 2;";
 $custres = mysql_query($custsql);
 $custrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($custres);
 $itemssql = "SELECT products.*, orderitems.*, orderitems.id AS itemid FROM 
 products, orderitems WHERE orderitems.product_id =products.id AND order_id 
 = " . $custrow['id'];
 $itemsres = mysql_query($itemssql);
 if($itemsres === FALSE)
 die(mysql_error());
 $itemnumrows = mysql_num_rows($itemsres);
}
```

mysql_num_rows expects parameter 1 instead of boolean which is given by mysql_query and after i made that check now i have this sql error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require("config.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN']) == TRUE) {
header("Location: " . $config_basedir);
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$loginsql = "SELECT * FROM logins WHERE username = '" . $_POST['userBox']. 
"' AND password = '" . sha1($_POST['passBox']) . "'";
$loginres = mysql_query($loginsql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($loginres);
if($numrows == 1)
{

$loginrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($loginres);
session_start("SESS_LOGGEDIN");
session_start("SESS_USERNAME");
session_start("SESS_USERID");
$_SESSION['SESS_LOGGEDIN'] = 1;
$_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $loginrow['username'];
$_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] = $loginrow['id'];
$ordersql = "SELECT id FROM orders WHERE customer_id = " . 
$_SESSION['SESS_USERID'] . " AND status < 2"; $orderres = 
mysql_query($ordersql); $orderrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($orderres); 
session_start("SESS_ORDERNUM"); $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'] = 
$orderrow['id']; header("Location: ".$config_basedir);
}
else {
header("Location: http://" .$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . 
"?error=1");
}
}
else {
require("header.php");
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should check the value of $_SESSION['SESS_ORDERNUM'].

The error means the created query($sql) is not valid, so you should debug $sql.

Comment: Yep. In order to do so, right after you define the `$sql` variable, stick a `echo $sql` and tell us what it says.